# using the same css for more than 1 image

Tags: css, html

I hope I use the right terminology (im a very amateur coder)
I have 2 images and I want to apply the same css on them but with minimum work, like when using:

```
h1, h2 {bla bla code}
```

So I tried

```
.btn-app img .btn-app2 img {
   margin-left: 10px;
    width: auto;
    height: 50px;}
```

but it doesnt work.
can it be done?

Mega thanks and nice to meet you all! =)

Comment: Add a separating comma between  .btn-app img and .btn-app2 img , like so : .btn-app img, .btn-app2 img {

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a comma there. The comma needs to be applied between each selector.

Your selectors are

```
.btn-app img
```

which selects all child `img` elements of `.btn-app` and

```
.btn-app2 img
```

which selects all child `img` elements of `.btn-app2`. 
 
So your code should be:

```
.btn-app img, .btn-app2 img {
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: auto;
    height: 50px;
}
```

If you're completely new to CSS and that wasn't just a typo, I'd also suggest having a read [here](https://www.thoughtco.com/comma-in-css-selectors-3467052).

Answer (score 0):

A missing comma. You already showed that in the example you are following

```
.btn-app img, .btn-app2 img {
       margin-left: 10px;
        width: auto;
        height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```css
/* you were missing some commas and > here */
.btn-app>img, .btn-app2>img
{
   position:relative;
   float:left;
   margin-left: 100px;
   height: 50px;
   border:10px solid #09f; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>

<!-- Works for images inside containers -->
<div class="btn-app">
  <img src="https://beebom.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg" alt="img1" height="70" width="70" />
</div>
<div class="btn-app2">
  <img src="https://beebom.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg" alt="img2" height="70" width="70" />
</div>


<br style="clear:both" />
<br/>


<!-- But it won't work for them -->

<!-- Images with class names -->
<img class="btn-app" src="https://beebom.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg"  alt="img3" height="70" width="70" />
<img class="btn-app2" src="https://beebom.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg"  alt="img4" height="70" width="70" />
<br/>
<!-- Images without class names -->
<img src="https://beebom.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg" alt="img5" height="70" width="70" />
<img src="https://beebom.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg" alt="img6" height="70" width="70" />

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I doubt this is what OP wanted

Comment: @NullDev I saw that too, so I edited to add the classes to images. It works with that also.

Comment: @NullDev try making a snippet of your code. I think it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Why would a snippet be necessary in this scenario? OP hasn't provided any HTML code. The simple explanation on whats going wrong should do it ;) Also, you're code does indeed work. However, by writing the `img` selector alone, both `.btn-app` and `.btn-app2` are obsolet since all images are targeted. That's not what OP wanted. It simply selects all `img` elements on that page.

Comment: @NullDev You were right my example did isolate only images. I edited to a better answer. Thanks. Though I tried your code and not only does it target the image but it targets the image container also, and, it does not work if the image itself has the class on it.

Comment: The code I provided does not target the container. That's the purpose of child selectors. (If you don't believe me, [proof is here](https://jsfiddle.net/g4mzrdbx/). If the CSS would target the container, it should be `50px`. But it's not.). As for the class on the image itself: That's supposed to happen. The `img` element has no `img` element as child. So it does not apply.

Comment: @NullDev Check out this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t6u3uspn/1/). It clearly shows your code does not work. Your code is the btn3, btn4 (bottom half). And, that you are targeting the  `.btn3` container as well.

Comment: That is incorrect. I do not know what you are trying to prove with this fiddle, as you literally wrote `.btn-app3, .btn-app4 img` which of course targets the container. But that is **not my code**. If you want we can continue this conversation in the discussion chat. I will then try to elaborate.

Comment: @NullDev It's my fault I haven't checked your fiddle when you sent it, it's your fault `you didn't tell me you made changes`. You had `.btn-app, .btn-app2 img` there, I commented because it didn't work at all, then you changed and now you are trying to convince me that I am wrong and that I don't know what I was talking about? Nice try. Your code now works for the same scenarios like mine. It also doesn't target images that have `class="btn-app"` but rather just images that are inside containers with classes `btn-app`  and `btn-app2`. It's ok now.

Comment: Excuse me? I never wrote `.btn-app, .btn-app2 img`. Not in my post, nor in the jsfiddle. See my [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48177660/revisions) and also see my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177597/using-the-same-css-for-more-than-1-image/48177705?noredirect=1#comment83336408_48177705). I never edited it (indicated by a small pen icon). So the link hasn't been changed. And the fiddle is in its initial version (see the URL, it doesn't end with a version number).

Comment: @NullDev If it is my mistake I apologize, the proof you are showing is strong proof. Though I know what I saw and maybe you don't know but there is a `5 min period` inside which editting is not captured. If you made changes inside this period it will not show in the history. There is no point in continuing this conversation, either I was wrong and in that case I apologize or you were. It doesn't matter. All I can see is your code works now. Everything is fine.